# Python and Discord bot - Websocket problem

Tags: python, exception, websocket, discord.py, bots

I'm trying to create a discord bot that check every message on one Discord channel and print something on another private channel according to the message printed on the first one. Everything works very well so this is not my problem.

My problem is about websocket, I would like to make this bot working everyday without shut down.

After a few hours, I get this message :

```
File "/Users/Name/opt/anaconda3/envs/Algo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/websocket/_socket.py", line 86, in recv
    raise WebSocketConnectionClosedException("socket is already closed.")
websocket._exceptions.WebSocketConnectionClosedException: socket is already closed.
```

It seems that my websocket stops working and I don't know why. Do you think there is a way to avoid this ? Or maybe adding a line that would starts the bot again when this error comes.

Here is the full code if you want to check :

````
import websocket, json, threading, time, discord
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
from discord.embeds import Embed
from discord.ext import tasks

client = discord.Client()

def send_json_request(ws,request):
    ws.send(json.dumps(request))

def receive_json_response(ws):
    response = ws.recv()
    if response:
        return json.loads(response)

def heartbeat(interval,ws):
    print('Hearbeat begin')
    while True:
        time.sleep(interval)
        heartbeatJSON= {
            'op':1,
            'd': 'null'
        }
        send_json_request(ws,heartbeatJSON)
        print("Heartbeat sent")

ws = websocket.WebSocket()
ws.connect("wss://gateway.discord.gg/?v=6&encoding=json")
event = receive_json_response(ws)

heartbeat_interval = event["d"]["heartbeat_interval"] / 1000
threading._start_new_thread(heartbeat,(heartbeat_interval,ws))
token = "TOKEN"

payload = {
    "op":2,
    "d":{
        "token":token,
        "properties":{
            "$os":'windows',
            "$browser":'brave',
            "$device":"pc"
        }
    }
}

send_json_request(ws,payload)
count_apparition = []

@tasks.loop(seconds = 1)
async def test():
    channel = client.get_channel("CHAN TO SEND MESSAGE") 
    while True:
        event = receive_json_response(ws)
        try:
            if (event['d']['channel_id'] == "CHAN TO LOOK AT"): 
                content = event['d']['embeds'] 
                for i in content :
                    print(i['description'])
                    crypto = i['description'].split()[i['description'].split().index('to')-2].split("(")[0] 
                    print(crypto)
                    count_apparition.append(crypto)
                    print(count_apparition)
                    t = Counter(count_apparition)
                    DATA = tuple(t.most_common())
                    s = ['Tickers          Apparitions'] 
                    for data in DATA: 
                        s.append('        '.join([str(item).center(10, ' ') for item in data]))
                    d = '```'+'\n'.join(s) + '```'  
                    embed = discord.Embed(title = '** MY TITLE', description = d)  
                await channel.send(embed = embed)
                op_code = event('op')
                if op_code == 11:
                    print('heartbeat received')
        except:
            pass

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot ready")
    test.start()

client.run('PRIVATE KEY')
````

Comment: You'll need to handle ws close events, Discord can close the ws anytime and it's your responsibility to reconnect. There are many reasons for this and you'll need to handle appropriately: https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/opcodes-and-status-codes#gateway-gateway-close-event-codes.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use websocket library which is synchronous whilst discord.py is asynchronous. This will cause blocking behaviours. You can use websocket provided by the aiohttp library.

Comment: And do you have any idea on how I can reconnect ? Or any documentation about that ? I tried to do that but it's a bit hard, I don't understand how to deal with that WebSocketConnectionClosedException

Comment: Check out the relevant resume info here: https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#resuming

Comment: @Taku I have sent resume (opcode 6) to resume_gateway_url (stored from ready message) with session_id (stored from ready message) and last sequence (stored from last opcodes 0 message). But after that, no hello nor new heartbeat. I also tried to just simply created new Websockets with default gateway URL "wss://gateway.discord.gg/?v=10&encoding=json" expecting reset of authentication, but do not hear hello nor new heartbeat. Would you know why?